# Expanding asterisk in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, escaping, glob

I'm trying to run `find`, and exclude several directories listed in an array.  I'm finding some weird behavior when it's expanding, though, which is causing me issues:

```
~/tmp> skipDirs=( "./dirB" "./dirC" )
~/tmp> bars=$(find . -name "bar*" -not \( -path "${skipDirs[0]}/*" $(printf -- '-o -path "%s/\*" ' "${skipDirs[@]:1}") \) -prune); echo $bars
./dirC/bar.txt ./dirA/bar.txt
```

This did not skip `dirC` as I wold have expected.  The problem is that the print expands the quotes around `"./dirC"`.

```
~/tmp> set -x 
+ set -x
~/tmp> bars=$(find . -name "bar*" -not \( -path "${skipDirs[0]}/*" $(printf -- '-o -path "%s/*" ' "${skipDirs[@]:1}") \) -prune); echo $bars
+++ printf -- '-o -path "%s/*" ' ./dirC
++ find . -name 'bar*' -not '(' -path './dirB/*' -o -path '"./dirC/*"' ')' -prune
+ bars='./dirC/bar.txt
./dirA/bar.txt'
+ echo ./dirC/bar.txt ./dirA/bar.txt
./dirC/bar.txt ./dirA/bar.txt
```

If I try to remove the quotes in the `$(print..)`, then the `*` gets expanded immediately, which also gives the wrong results.  Finally, if I remove the quotes and try to escape the `*`, then the `\` escape character gets included as part of the filename in the find, and that does not work either.   I'm wondering why the above does not work, and, what would work?   I'm trying to avoid using `eval` if possible, but currently I'm not seeing a way around it.

Note: This is very similar to: [Finding directories with find in bash using a exclude list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139523/finding-directories-with-find-in-bash-using-a-exclude-list), however, the posted solutions to that question seem to have the issues I listed above.

Comment: A slight variation of the same problem is http://stackoverflow.com/q/28682013/45375

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safe approach is to build your array explicitly:

```
#!/bin/bash

skipdirs=( "./dirB" "./dirC" )

skipdirs_args=( -false )
for i in "${skipdirs[@]}"; do
    args+=( -o -type d -path "$i" )
done

find . \! \( \( "${skipdirs_args[@]}" \) -prune \) -name 'bar*'
```

I slightly modify the logic in your find since you had a slight (logic) error in there: your command was:

```
find -name 'bar*' -not stuff_to_prune_the_dirs
```

How does `find` proceed? it will parse the files tree and when it finds a file (or directory) that matches `bar*` then it will apply the `-not ...` part. That's really not what you want! your `-prune` is never going to be applied!

Look at this instead:

```
find . \! \( -type d -path './dirA' -prune \)
```

Here `find` will completely prune the directory `./dirA` and print everything else. Now *it's among everything else that you want to apply the filter `-name 'bar*'`!* the order is very important! there's a big difference between this:

```
find . -name 'bar*' \! \( -type d -path './dirA' -prune \)
```

and this:

```
find . \! \( -type d -path './dirA' -prune \) -name 'bar*'
```

The first one doesn't work as expected at all! The second one is fine.

**Notes.**

- I'm using `\!` instead of `-not` as `\!` is POSIX, `-not` is an extension not specified by POSIX. You'll argue that `-path` is not POSIX either so it doesn't matter to use `-not`. That's a detail, use whatever you like.
- You had to use some dirty trick to build your commands to skip your dir, as you had to consider the first term separately from the other. By initializing the array with `-false`, I don't have to consider any terms specially.
- I'm specifying `-type d` so that I'm sure I'm pruning directories.
- Since my pruning really applies to the directories, I don't have to include wildcards in my exclude terms. This is funny: your problem that seemingly is about wildcards that you can't handle disappears completely when you use `find` appropriately as explained above.
- Of course, the method I gave really applies with wildcards too. For example, if you want to exclude/prune all subdirectories called `baz` inside subdirectories called `foo`, the `skipdirs` array given by

  ```
  skipdirs=( "./*/foo/baz" "./*/foo/*/baz" )
  ```

  will work fine!

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the quotes you are using on `"%s/*"` aren't doing what you think they are.

That is to say, you think you need the quotes on `"%s/*"` to prevent the results from the `printf` from being globbed however that isn't what is happening. Try the same thing without the directory separator and with files that start and end with double quotes and you'll see what I mean.

```
$ ls
"dirCfoo"
$ skipDirs=( "dirB" "dirC" )
$ printf '%s\n' -- -path "${skipDirs[0]}*" $(printf -- '-o -path "%s*" ' "${skipDirs[@]:1}")
-path
dirB*
-o
-path
"dirCfoo"
$ rm '"dirCfoo"'
$ printf -- '%s\n' -path "${skipDirs[0]}*" $(printf -- '-o -path "%s*" ' "${skipDirs[@]:1}")
-path
dirB*
-o
-path
"dirC*"
```

See what I mean? The quotes aren't being handled specially by the shell. They just happen not to glob in your case.

This issue is part of why things like what is discussed at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 don't work.

To do what you want here I believe you need to create the find arguments array manually.

```
sD=(-path /dev/null)
for dir in "${skipDirs}"; do
    sD+=(-o -path "$dir")
done
```

and then expand "${sD[@]}" on the `find` command line (`-not \( "${sD[@]}" \)` or so).

And yes, I believe this makes the answer you linked to incorrect (though the other answer might work (for non-whitespace, etc. files) because of the array indirection that is going on.

Comment: Kudos for explaining the quoting issue. Let me try a summary: The command substitution is _unquoted_, so its output is subject to shell expansions, including globbing. The double quotes become a _literal_ part of the tokens they enclose - they are _not_ parsed as a double-quoted string by the shell (only `eval` would do that). So, globbing _is_ applied to _literal_ `"*"`, which will _typically_ not match anything (since most filenames aren't enclosed in literal double quotes). What ultimately goes wrong is that the literal double quotes are passed to `find` _as part of the argument_.